# “Might” vs. “Maybe”

Tags: colloquialisms

Is it a correct form to say while talking?

1. "I might go"  => i.e., *maybe* I will go
2. "he might be available"  => i.e., *maybe* he will be available.

Comment: The correct expression is **maybe**. For two words to be correct, the structure of the sentence has to different, e.g., "It **may be** the case that he'll go". I see that **may be** has been edited to read **maybe**, which is correct for this question, but I'll leave my comment anyway.

Comment: General reference. Look up *might* in the [dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=might&ls=a), and you'll see that it means "used for saying that there is a possibility that something is true, or that something will happen." Also, you _might_ want to support our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). I _would_ appreciate it if you did.

Answer (score 1):

NOAD:

> usage: Traditionalists insist that one should distinguish between may (present tense) and might (past tense) in expressing possibility: I may have some dessert after dinner if I'm still hungry | I might have known that the highway would be closed because of the storm. In casual use, though, may and might are generally interchangeable: they might take a vacation next month | he may have called earlier, but the answering machine was broken.